# find a way to keep size unchangable when i change the time series frequency in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

```
before transformation:
bf_data = pd.DataFrame({"ts":['2020-1-1 00:03:00','2020-1-1 00:12:00','2020-1-1 00:07:00','2020-1-1 00:18:00','2020-1-1 00:22:00'],'values':[0.2,0.3,0.5,0.9,1]})
after transformation:
af_data = pd.DataFrame({"ts":['2020-1-1 00:00:00','2020-1-1 00:10:00','2020-1-1 00:00:00','2020-1-1 00:10:00','2020-1-1 00:20:00'],'values':[0.2,0.3,0.5,0.9,1]})
```

first ,i need keep the size or shape of af_data is same as the bf_data's
second,element in bf_data["ts"] ,if it's minute is in [0,10),can be transformed '2020-1-1 00:00:00',minute is in [10,20) can be transformed '2020-1-1 00:10:00' and so on

Answer (score 0):

Convert [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), [`floor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) to `10min` and convert back to string:

```
bf_data['ts'] = (pd.to_datetime(bf_data['ts']).dt.floor('10min')
                   .dt.strftime('%Y-%-m-%-d %H:%M:%S')
                )
```

Output:

```
                  ts  values
0  2020-1-1 00:00:00     0.2
1  2020-1-1 00:10:00     0.3
2  2020-1-1 00:00:00     0.5
3  2020-1-1 00:10:00     0.9
4  2020-1-1 00:20:00     1.0
```